# Better way to apply CSS to the targeted element

Tags: html, css, specifications, bem

How to organize the HTML structure and apply CSS. Which does not conflict with others CSS.

Which is the better way to apply the CSS to the targeted element?

---

**Way 1:**

```
.PARENT_1 .CHILD:first-child {

}

<div class="PARENT_1">
    <div class="COMMON">
        <div class="CHILD"></div>   <!-- Targeted element -->
        <div class="CHILD"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Way 2:**

```
.PARENT_1_CHILD_1 {

}

<div class="PARENT_1">
    <div class="COMMON">
        <div class="CHILD PARENT_1_CHILD_1"></div>  <!-- Targeted element -->
        <div class="CHILD"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Any other way to improve **CSS Specificity**?
Can I use **Bem Methodology**?

Comment: IMO, there's no better way. It depends how easy it is to implement, scale, reuse and read. But in the end, it has to deliver the intended layout you want.

Comment: My suggestion, i will got with way 1 as what if all child are coming dynamic then you can't give different class to all child so better go with way 1 and use with child but be in mind, it depends on condition and need of client/yours.

Comment: `.COMMON CHILD:first-child` Use camelCase, or lowercase with dashes, for readiblity. Frequent use of all uppercase will lessen the emphasis that it normally implies.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to apply CSS only to one element at a time, use an id for the element e.g.
2. if you target only one element wrapped inside a div, you can write it down in css like this: #divname > #something.a (when #something.a is first  element inside the wrapper div) OR**
   simply #divname #something.a - this will find the  element with id anywhere inside the wrapper div.

Hope you got the point. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are css Methodologies you can find a depth explanation:

Examples of CSS Methodologies:
OOCSS, SMACSS, Idiomatic CSS and BEM

[Title CSS Simple Approach CSS Class Naming](https://www.sitepoint.com/title-css-simple-approach-css-class-naming/)